# GWT/JSNI this. is not replace with a reference to the instance

Tags: gwt, jsni

I have the following code in a GWT class:

```
private native JavaScriptObject getRequest() /*-{
    var request = ...;

    request.onOpen = function(response) {
this.@com.mdarveau.fnp.client.Client::onOpen(Lcom/mdarveau/fnp/client/Response;)(response);
    };

    return request;
}-*/;

void onOpen( Response response ) {
    Window.alert( "Got response " + response );
}
```

However, when the function associated with `request.onOpen` is called, the "this variable" is not replaced with a reference to the compiled GWT class. Using chrome javascript console and debugger I see that it looks like a reference to the `request` object.

Any idea why? I also have jquery loaded, could there be a conflict?

Comment: Got it: you need to get a reference to 'this' in the native code and then use it in the 'function' block: var theInstance = this; and then request.onOpen = function(response) {
theInstance.@com.mdarveau.fnp.client.Client::onOpen(Lcom/mdarveau/fnp/client/Response;)(response);
    };

Comment: please post your findings as an answer, so others may benefit from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it: you need to get a reference to `this` in the native code and then use it in the `function` block:

```
var theInstance = this;
```

and then

```
request.onOpen = function(response) {
    theInstance.@com.mdarveau.fnp.client.Client::onOpen(Lcom/mdarveau/fnp/client/Res‌​ponse;)(response);
};
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Brilliant!