# Calling a method inside a javascript function using GWT jsni

Tags: gwt, jsni

What I want is to call this code

```
public native void eventClickHandler( String id) /*-{
  $wnd.jQuery('#' + id).bind('jqplotDataClick',function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
    this.@it.codegen.gwt.jqplot.client.charts.JQChart::onClick(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)(seriesIndex, pointIndex);
  });
}-*/;
```

Here the onClick method is a normal java method and I'm using GWT and JSNI interface for this.
Thanks in advance!..

Comment: its not working sorry I think I forgot to mention it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GWT/JSNI this. is not replace with a reference to the instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406769/gwt-jsni-this-is-not-replace-with-a-reference-to-the-instance)

Comment: [the use of `this` is somewhat risky](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html), as it refers to the function owner. is the JSNI method a member of an [overlay type](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/OverlayTypes)? please enclose more context code, and some generated exceptions, if exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used jQuery before? `this` has particular meaning inside a function passed to jQuery. Even in JSNI, while it is in a Java file, it won't behave like a Java `this`, but like a JavaScript `this`.

Try this instead:

```
public native void eventClickHandler( String id) /*-{
  var origThis = this;
  $wnd.jQuery('#' + id).bind('jqplotDataClick',function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
    origThis.@it.codegen.gwt.jqplot.client.charts.JQChart::onClick(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)(seriesIndex, pointIndex);
  });
}-*/;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it seems that its still not working, have to find out a way to refer methods inside a jquery function.